# AWS Lightsail MySQL: Discrepancy between Total Database Size and Storage Metrics

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-lightsail

I'm currently managing a database hosted on an AWS Lightsail server with a 120 GB plan. I wanted to monitor the disk space usage of my MySQL database, so I executed the following SQL query to check the total size of the tables:

sql
Copy code
SELECT ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS "Total Database Size (GB)"
FROM information_schema.tables;
The query returned a total of approximately 17 GB as the size of the database. However, when I checked the storage usage metrics on the AWS Lightsail dashboard, it's only showing 1 GB in use.

I'm trying to understand why there's a discrepancy between the size reported by the SQL query and the metrics shown in the AWS Lightsail dashboard. I verified the binary logs using SHOW BINARY LOGS, but I don't have SUPER privileges to execute that command.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation or knows what might be causing this difference in disk space usage? Are there any other areas I should investigate to find out what's consuming the additional disk space?

Any help, suggestions, or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Information:

AWS Lightsail plan: 120 GB
MySQL version: (5.7.38)

I connected to the database, cleaned up old tables, and accessed it using other management platforms like DBeaver and Workbench.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.